# Is there a story behind Darth Maul's double bladed lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber, the-phantom-menace, darth-maul

One of the most famous lightsabers is Darth Maul's double bladed lightaber.

**But is there an in-universe backstory of how/why he has one?**

When he battles Obi-Wan & Qui-Gon Jinn in Episode I, his lightsaber proved to be very useful, which also makes me wonder why more people don't have one too.

I'd love to know if there are any backstories which let us know where this iconic lightsaber came from in the film.

Both canon and Legends are acceptable.

Comment: Do you mean in-universe or out?

Comment: ..and related - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11575/shouldnt-darth-mauls-double-bladed-lightsaber-have-broken?rq=1

Comment: also - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Double-bladed_lightsaber

Comment: @Paulie_D I meant in-universe, and thank you for the links I'll check them out!

Comment: Canon only or Legends too?

Comment: @Null Legends too

Comment: In the future please specify that in the question body and use the tag as I've just edited. Thanks.

Comment: @Null duly noted, Thanks for editing this for me, much rather have a better structured question. I'll remember next time.

Comment: In-universe, out-universe, it's badass either way

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure the Rule of Cool exists in a galaxy far, far away just as much as it does here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is covered in [Star Wars Tales #10](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Tales_10). Maul is off killing Jedi survivors when he comes across a weapons master who bests him with a simple wooden staff. Recognising that he needs an "edge", he comes up with his funky two-bladed lightsaber.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The process of making his lightsaber is also described in [Darth Maul: Shadow Hunter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Maul:_Shadow_Hunter).

> *The intensity of his connection to the Force brought back a memory:
>   another day of intense focus of his power. The day he had constructed
>   his lightsaber. Maul was not wont to revisit his past, unless doing so
>   somehow served his master, but the satisfaction of the creation, the
>   perfection of focus, and the highly charged connection to the Force
>   that had wrought his weapon stood out now in his memory.*
>
> *The specialized furnace, which he had created from plans taken from
>   his master’s Sith Holocron, had radiated an intense heat as it shaped
>   the synthetic crystals needed for his lightsaber. But rather than
>   leaving the kiln chamber and allowing them to form on their own, he
>   had remained near the device, concentrating on the metamorphosing
>   gems, using the Force to purify and refine the lattice of the
>   molecular matrices.*
>
> *Most Jedi used natural crystals in their lightsabers; Adegan crystals
>   were the gems of choice. Most of the other components of a lightsaber
>   were easily obtained—power cells, field energizers, stabilizing rings,
>   flux apertures—but not the crystals themselves. They had to be mined
>   in the Adega system, deep within the Outer Rim Territories. The
>   difficulty of using natural materials meant that the alignment process
>   could take a long time—and the calibration had to be perfect, because
>   mismatched crystals could destroy not only the lightsaber, but its
>   creator.*
>
> *Finding and aligning the crystals was a Jedi test, but it was not the
>   way of the Sith. The dark masters of the Force preferred to create
>   their own synthetic crystals, to match the harmonics in the searing
>   heat of a crucible and thus take their creation of the weapon to a
>   deeper level.*
>
> *Maul had sat by the furnace, focusing his hatred of the Jedi to a
>   fiery peak and expanding his control of the Force, which he used to
>   manipulate the molecular structures of the four gems required for his
>   double-bladed weapon. The choice to make two blades instead of one had
>   been an easy one. Only an expert would even think of trying to handle
>   a double-bladed weapon, and he would be no less than an expert. The
>   glory of the Sith required it, as did his master.*
>
> *Not even the compressed ferrocrete walls of the pressurized chamber
>   could entirely contain the intense temperature required to form the
>   crystals. Hour after hour had passed, the searing heat washing over
>   the apprentice. But his control had not wavered; the pain had not
>   swayed his focus. Layer after countless layer of the crystals had been
>   laid down, aligned, and perfected. It had taken days, days without
>   food or water or sleep, but eventually he had sensed their readiness.
>   Then he had deactivated the furnace and cracked it open. There,
>   sitting in the formation crucibles, had been his four perfect
>   crystals.*

Comment: So does this mean that the double ended lightsaber (and presumably the fighting style to utilize it) is unique to Darth Maul? Maybe Donnie Yen's character in "Rogue One" is Darth Maul (or this bo staff wielding Jedi) in disguise :)

Comment: @JasonK - There are other double-ended lightsabers in both the Disney and "Legends" canons; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Double-bladed_lightsaber. Ventress had one, as did Maul's brother. Apparently the Jedi also used a variant called a "saber-staff".

Comment: `> His weapon, a plain wooden stick, was longer than mine.`... so his plan is to make a double-bladed saber, which he can only grab in the middle....?  He hasn't increased his own weapon's length at all, since he can only hold his in the middle (unlike with the wooden staff, which can, and will, be grabbed anywhere).  Note that using a double-bladed saber requires a **vastly** different technique, since many moves for single-bladed weapons would put an opposite end through the wielder!  If he wants to surprise this guy, I would have just pulled out a blaster.

Comment: @clockwork-Muse - I struggled with that one as well. In the end I decided that it made some sense because the combined lengths of both blades is longer

Comment: That doesn't make it make an even remote amount of sense. Whilst it's clear that he might gain some advantage, and he may gain surprise in addition, pure length is definitely not one of them.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse This is the same guy that gets cut in half even with the high ground...

Comment: @DeadMG - In the comic, the [element of surprise](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YQbMy.png) is what wins it for him.

Comment: @Valorum - yeah, something like that is about the only way he could win that fight.  Of course, how much of a moron do you have to be to not go, "Hey, I fought this guy earlier, and it looks like he duplicated his saber and stuck them together...".  And even then, the extra handle length alone would be a problem.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse the double-bladed saber has a handle that is over twice as long as a normal saber, so it's not true that he did not gain any length. He gained like an extra 12 to 14" in reach. But he also made his lightsaber handle an easier and more enticing target for strikes.